# immutability of const in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and have a question about immutability in es6 to help my understanding of immutability.

For example, I know this is invalid in JSX as it is reassigning a const.

```
const helloWorld = 'Hello World';
helloWorld = 'Bye World';
```

however, this seems valid:

```
const helloWorld = {greeting: 'hello World'};
helloWorld.greeting = 'bye world';
```

In essence, the concept i'm trying to wrap my brain around is the idea that while although `helloWorld` is immutable, the value it holds is not. *How* and *why* does this still represent immutability? And why would you use it in this fashion instead of using a `let` variable?

Thanks and apologies for the noob question if it is as such! :)

Comment: This is nothing to do with react and jsx. Read basic javascript first before diving into frameworks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 2):

First `const` is not a part of JSX, it's language feature in ECMAScript6. `const` only make the variable a constant and the value it refers is still mutable.

If you want to make the value immutable, use `Object.freeze` or a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: indeed, i'm aware of this being the way it works. my question is more to the _why_.

Comment: Simply `const` doesn't represent immutability. If you have seen using `const` inside react components that because those variables are not meant to change and it has nothing do with immutability.